Comparing the RMSE between OLS- and Quasi-Poisson/PPML-Estimated Models?
We are trying to compare the prediction performance of a (log-transformed) Ordinary Least Squares (OLS)-estimated model and a Quasi-Poisson model with a log-link (also called PPML in Stata).
In doing so, we refer to the Root Mean Squared Error $\text{RMSE} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left( y_i - \hat{y}_i \right)^2}$.
By this measure, the Poisson model performs better. However, we are wondering whether this is an appropriate way to compare the models. Shouldn't OLS minimize the RMSE regardless, given that the square root is a monotonically-increasing function?
From a substantive point of view, both Poisson and OLS models are acceptable, given that we are working with count data, but with a large sample and large values. Broadly, there seem to have been contradictory answers on Stackexchange in previous thread.
